# cannot extract JSON

Tags: ios, json, alamofire

Hello I am trying to extract a json. However I am getting an error saying `Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'NSData'`. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

```
    success: { (response) -> Void in
        var dataStream: Data = Data.init(referencing: response!)
        do {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataStream, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)as AnyObject
        }catch{
        }
        if let id = response!["money"]as? String {
            print(id)
        }

    }){ (error) -> Void in
        print("error")
    }
}
```

Update2

```
let request = Alamofire.request(apiUrl, method: .get)


    request.responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result
        {
        case .success:
            success(response.result.value as AnyObject)
        case .failure(let error):
            failure(error as NSError)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because the error message seems to be misleading. the initializer `init(referencing` is inappropriate anyway because it makes a reference type from the value type which is useless in your case. I recommend to use the `.responseJSON` parameter of Alamofire to return deserialized JSON.

Comment: I actually have that implemented update 2

Comment: tried to print response.result.value???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
var dataStream: Data = Data.init(referencing: response!)
```

in Docs

> init(referencing reference: NSData)

response should be of type NSData not Data , you may try

```
let responseDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any]
```

note cast to expected return whether it's dictionary or array

this

```
 if let id = response!["money"]as? String {
        print(id)
    }
```

should be replaced with

```
  if let id = responseDict!["money"]as? String {
        print(id)
    }
```

You can try `Alamofire` with `SwiftyJson`

```
        Alamofire.request("https://yourlinkdownloadjson/abc").responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)

            if let json = response.data {
                let data = JSON(data: json)
                print("data\(data["money"])")

            }
        }
```

Comment: Hello Thank you for you answer. Where did data! come from?

Comment: what do you use to call the web service , i mean NSURLConnection or NSUrlSession ?

Comment: It should be `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response, options: .allowFragments)`

Comment: I'm using Alamofire. If I do that jsonObject' produces 'Any', not the expected contextual result type 'AnyObject' error occurs....

Comment: *`Any` is **not** same as `AnyObject`*

Comment: I mean in cast if he uses if let id = response!["money"]as? String  then it should be if let id = data!["money"]as? String  where data casted as [String:Any]

Comment: what the return structure you expect array or dictionary??